# Connection Timeout Expired SSMS 2016 when Imported bacpac file

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, sql-server-2016

I have tried to Import data tier application (*.bacpac file) through SSMS 2016.I need to put that database into Azure. Then it gives below mentioned exception.But I can access the Azure's existing database's tables through SSMS. Can you tell me why this is happening ?

```
 TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
    ------------------------------

    Failed to connect to server (local). (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

    ------------------------------
    ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

    Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to 
consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-
login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The 
duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] 
initialization=1912; handshake=3839;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

    For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-2&LinkId=20476

    ------------------------------

    The wait operation timed out

    ------------------------------
    BUTTONS:

    OK
    ------------------------------
```

[image]

When I try to connect the Azure Sql instance through SSMS 2016,it gives below error.But still I can access the tables and etc on the SSMS. No problem there on accessing those items.But it gives the error as shown below on the first time.May be this error is related to the original one too.Any help would be highly appreciated ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshots you have posted it looks like you are having problems connecting to a database on your local machine. One of the causes of the 'connection timeout' error is when you don't have a SQL Server instance running. [There is a technet article with steps that could help you resolve this.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190181%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

As an aside, SSMS provides a wizard to help you migrate a database on your local machine directly to an Azure SQL database without fussing with *.bacpac files. [Perhaps that could help you solve your problem as well](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate-compatible-using-ssms-migration-wizard/).

Comment: I don't have any problem to connect to the `localhost`.It's working fine.This was happened when I was trying to connect azure database.Your second option also an alternative approach. But I need to sort out the above issue.

Comment: This is good to know, thanks for commenting. Do you regularly experience this issue, or is it transient?

Comment: This is always happen when I try to connect to the Azure data base.